# Xcode Build Errors Unity 4.7.2

Tags: unity, ios, xcode

These two errors are doing my head in. New to Xcode. So please advise thank you.

FYI

I did not touch or modify anything of the Xcode that was generated by Unity. Upon opening there is a warning that says to set to recommended settings. Other than that just set the provisional file. Set the simulator device then pressed play but these two errors keep showing!

## include "Unity/GlesHelper.h" file not found

## include "UI/Keyboard.h" file not found

[image]

[image]

Comment: Under the target build settings, what contents do you have in the "header search path" settings?

Comment: Also, under the target settings, you may have a search path set for the header files under "other c flags settings". You may want to check there too.

Comment: http://postimg.org/gallery/2jt3pay1y/ uploaded some pictures to what i see is the project search path where the project is located.

Comment: Select the "header search path" field and paste the contents into your question above so we could see the full path.

Comment: When I select the header search path field I find this $(PROJECT_DIR). Thank you.

Comment: https://s9.postimg.org/yl6aun2hr/Screen_Shot_2016_08_13_at_17_20_23.png here under project its empty.

Comment: The header search path is actually set at the target level. The answer below may help you.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 possibilities given what you've posted. Since I've not used Unity, I don't know which it is, but I'll explain both:

1. If Unity isn't a framework, then you need to just add the path to the Unity folder to your target's "Header Search Paths". Given how the `#include`s are written, my guess is that that's the case.
2. If Unity is a framework, then you haven't added the Unity.framework to your target. I don't know if Unity ships as a framework, but if it does, you need to add the framework to your target by going to the target's "Build Phases" and clicking the "+" button under "Link Binary With Libraries". From there, click the "Add Other…" button and navigate to wherever you put the Unity.framework. You also need to change the `#include "Unity/GlesHelper.h"` to `#include <Unity/GlesHelper.h>`. You may additionally need to add the Unity framework's headers path to your target's headers path. I have found instances where Xcode didn't automatically add the headers path of a framework after adding the framework to the target.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say need to add the unity folder to the target's header path. Do you mean the actual unity project folder? or the Xcode project folder that Unity generates for you?

Comment: The path to wherever Unity stores the headers on your hard drive. (The headers being things like `Unity/GlesHelper.h`, etc.) Not the Xcode project you're working on but the headers from the Unity library/framework/whatever it is.